# Unexpected output in a linked list using C

Tags: singly-linked-list

I've just started learning C and am fairly a beginner.
Today in school we learned linked list and I was able to put up a code...which thankfully is running without errors.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
struct node
{
    int data;
    struct node *next;
}*head;//*temp;
void create(struct node **h,int num)
{
    int i;
    struct node *temp=*h;
    for(i=0;;i++)
    {
        if(i>=num)
        break;
        temp->data=i;
        temp->next=malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    temp->next=NULL;
}
    void display(struct node **h)
{   
    struct node *temp=*h;
    while(temp->next!=NULL)
    {
        printf("%d->",temp->data);
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    printf("\b\b  \b\b");
}
void append_end(struct node **h,int val)
{
    struct node *temp=*h,*temp1;
    //printf("'%d'",val);
    while(temp->next!=NULL)
    temp=temp->next;
    temp1=malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp1->data=val;
    temp1->next=NULL;
    temp->next=temp1;
}
void free_list(struct node **h)
{
    struct node *temp=*h,*tail;
    while(temp->next!=NULL)
    {
        tail=temp;
        temp=temp->next;
        free(tail);
    }
    h=NULL;
}
int main()
{
    head=malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    int i,num;
    scanf("%d",&num);
    create(&head,num);
    //display(&head);
    append_end(&head,5);
    append_end(&head,6);
    display(&head);
    /*temp=head;
    while(temp->next!=NULL)
    temp=temp->next;
    printf("%d",temp->data);*/
    free_list(&head);
    return 0;
}
```

The expected output should be
    0->1->2->3->5->6
for input of 4

But instead I'm getting
    0->1->2->3->(some garbage value)->5

I'll be glad if someone could point out my error(s), and/or link to any article that might help me in understanding the topic clearly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should depend less on global variables.  Also, you're over-relying on pointers.  You shouldn't have to be dealing with pointers to pointers with what you're doing.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply Wug...for global variables I'll just declare the structure in main...and I'll look up to make the code less reliant on pointers. But when using functions here doesn't it make more sense to use pointers to pointers??

Comment: I don't see any reason to, since in every one you just dereference it one level before using them.

Comment: I think your other problem, adding 5 and 6 to the end of the list, is really coming from the create() method..this is just from eyeballing it, but I believe your code causes the ->next reference for the last member to actually point to a new structure rather than null..so all the comparisons of temp->next==null don't work as you expect...

Comment: Okay I've figured out one of my mistakes
When displaying while loop should be temp!=NULL instead of temp->next!=NULL silly me :P
But now the output is 0->1->2->3->(some garbage value)->5->6 for an input of 4

Answer (score 2):

I've refactored your code.  You can see it here: http://ideone.com/nZ55i

1. Your code was ugly, so I tweaked it into my own style.  I suggest you find a style you like, that's easy for you to read.
2. Moved declaration of head into main method (used to be a global variable)
3. Functions that took pointer-to-pointer types for no reason have been modified to take pointers.
4. You used malloc(sizeof(struct node)) in at least 3 places, so I just up and made a function that does it for you.
5. Added a typedef to the declaration of the node struct, you can declare instances of it now with just `node derp;`
6. `create` function uses a for loop with an empty condition and a break, refactored to use a proper for loop with no break
7. The garbage value was caused by a bug in your create function that prevented it from writing the value to the last node it created.  To fix it, I moved stuff around so it always assigns the `data` field but doesn't allocate a new node if it's at the end
8. Failure to write the last item in the list was caused by a bug in the display function that caused it to terminate before displaying the last node.

If this is a homework question and you turn in my code, I will find you, drive to your house, and shoot a rotten potato through your bedroom window with a cannon.

Comment: Thanks for the code...yes yours is easy on the eyes...I'hope to find my style sometimes soon.
I know my problem now.
PS Don't worry its not even remotely related to homework.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I started to put this in the comments, but putting code in comments will get brickbats :). This is *not tested*, and there are myriad ways to approach it (given I've diagnosed the problem correctly :) ), but one way that might work to fix your create method is offered as follows: (Note that I've simplified your loop, just using the normal termination condition for the 'for' loop construct, and eliminated the 'if..break' within the loop as its no longer needed. The "->next" member will always be initialized to a new member if there's one left to create, otherwise its NULL, so we don't need the ending assignment:

```
void create(struct node **h,int num)
{
    int i;
    struct node *temp=*h;
    for(i=0;i<num;i++)
    {
        temp->data=i;
        if (i==(num-1))
           temp->next=NULL;
        else
           temp->next=malloc(sizeof(struct node));

        temp=temp->next;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks David...this create function makes sense and now I know what my problem was.

Comment: Just to get things a bit clearer. Are you saying 'replace void create with this', everything else is 'rather ok' OR are you just commenting on the create function?

Comment: Just suggesting an alternative way to implement the "create" method that, I think, fixes a small bug in the OP's version and tries to clarify the code a little. The refactored example by @Wug is very nice, so the organization it demonstrates mitigates the need for too much more comment from me in the broader vein of "code cleanup" or "organization."